# is it possible to iterate int array by reference with foreach in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to iterate an int array by reference in a C# foreach loop?

I mean something like this:

```
 int[] tab = new int[5];
 foreach (ref int i in tab)
 {
     i=5;
 }
```

thanks

Comment: Does this even compile? `int[] tab = new tab[5];` And why would you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with `tab[i] = 5;` ? Just use a regular for-loop or write a simple extension method that returns a KeyValuePair

Comment: You might want to look at `for` loop.

Comment: what speaks against Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(x=>5).ToArray() ?

Answer (score 3):

Since C# 7.3, it works, but you need to cast the array as a Span.

```cs
int[] tab = new int[5];

foreach (ref int i in tab.AsSpan()) {
    i = 5;
}

Console.WriteLine(tab.Sum()); // 25
```

Tested on Net Core 3.1 and Net 5.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why casting to a Span is required?

Comment: @ZheChen Good question, and I don't know exactly why. My guess is that a Span will fix the array in a precise and constant location in memory for the duration of the loop. Hence a safe ref is made possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to iterate an int array by reference in a C# foreach
>   loop?

No, `foreach` loop in C# is not designed to make changes to the collection it iterates. It uses a `readonly` local variable that cannot be used as an assignment target.

Still you can use `for` loop to do it :

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();

for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
   list[i] = new MyClass();
}
```

Or use LINQ :

```
list = list.Select(e => new MyClass()).ToList(); // note that this will create a copy of list
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a `foreach` loop will not allow the loop variable to reference another variable.  It will always copy the value out of the sequence and into a new variable.  To do what you're looking to do you'd need to use some structure other than a `foreach` loop.  While *technically* you could write your own `ForEach` method accepting a lambda where the parameter is a reference to an item in an array, the result...probably isn't worth it.

```
public delegate void ReferenceAction<T>(ref T param);
public static void ForEach<T>(T[] source, ReferenceAction<T> action)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        action(ref source[i]);
}
```

---

```
int[] tab = new int[5];
ForEach(tab, (ref int n) => n = 5);
```

There are almost certainly going to be better ways of accomplishing what you're trying to do without actually having a loop where the loop variable is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible in the exact same syntax as proposed in the question.

From Microsoft docs: Beginning with C# 7.3, if the enumerator's Current property returns a reference return value (ref T where T is the type of the collection element), you can declare the iteration variable with the ref or ref readonly modifier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

Example:

```
int val = 0;
int[] tab = new int[5];

foreach (ref int i in tab) {
    i = val++;
}

foreach (ref readonly var j in tab) {
    Console.WriteLine(j);
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: What sort of project did you create this in? I would love to use this feature but in a .NET Core 3.1 class library (C# 8) it is throwing compilation errors

Comment: Not compiling. Apparently you need to cast the array as a span to make it work. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @Dan Windows Forms and WPF using .NET framework 4.5